# Parallel.for Loop - result varies for each click .. why does this happen?

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2012

Following parallel.for loop uses data of a bitarray which is 300000 bits in length. and the data is fixed not to change. So the produced results "Count_of_Found_Pattern1" must be same no matter how many times I execute the function "check"

But, the issue is the values of "Count_of_Found_Pattern1" & "Count_of_Found_Pattern2" produce different values every time I execute the function "check" .. what have I done wrong?

when I check it using small amount of bits (about 16 bits instead of 300000) it produces good results. But, when the bitarray length is lengthier, it produces a total mess.

For Example:

**1st execution -->** Count_of_Found_Pattern1 = 150526 , Count_of_Found_Pattern2 = 97855

**2nd execution -->** Count_of_Found_Pattern1 = 45855 , Count_of_Found_Pattern2 = 187562

Regards!

```
Private Function check() 

        Dim Count_of_Found_Pattern1 As Int64 = 0
        Dim Count_of_Found_Pattern2 As Int64 = 0
        Dim stopwatch As New Stopwatch


        stopwatch.Start()

        Dim Current_Position1 As Int64 = 0 
        Dim Current_Position2 As Int64 = 1

        Parallel.For(0, lastbitarrayover2, Sub(countbits, loopstate)


                                               If BitArray(Current_Position1) = False And BitArray(Current_Position2) = True Then

                                                   Count_of_Found_Pattern1 = Count_of_Found_Pattern1 + 1
                                               End If

                                               If BitArray(Current_Position1) = True And BitArray(Current_Position2) = False Then

                                                   Count_of_Found_Pattern1 = Count_of_Found_Pattern1 + 1
                                               End If

                                               If BitArray(Current_Position1) = True And BitArray(Current_Position2) = True Then

                                                   Count_of_Found_Pattern2 = Count_of_Found_Pattern2 + 1

                                               End If

                                               If BitArray(Current_Position1) = False And BitArray(Current_Position2) = False Then

                                                   Count_of_Found_Pattern2 = Count_of_Found_Pattern2 + 1

                                               End If

                                               Current_Position1 = Current_Position1 + 2
                                               Current -Position2 = Current_Position2 + 2
                                               Numer_of_Completed_Iterations = Numer_of_Completed_Iterations + 1

                                           End Sub)


        Numer_of_Completed_Iterations = 0 'reset counter to 0


        stopwatch.Stop()
        TextBox1.Text = stopwatch.Elapsed.ToString

    End Function
```

Comment: as is implied by the one answer posted (as of time of this comment), you're running into a thread safety issue...the threads aren't guaranteed (and almost never actually do) run at the exact same speed, so your numbers are likely being botched up because one thread may process through 3 cycles before the other one processes through 1 (depending on cpu load, ect).  The reason this is more noticeable with larger sets, is because it's more likely that one of your cpu threads might stall out for a fraction of a second with a larger data set...

Comment: Current_Position1 and Current_Position2 are incremented in lockstep; are they supposed to start with different values?

Comment: @user2366842 : ohh, is that so, now I understand how threads work .. :) Thank you.

Comment: @JerryFederspiel : I'm so sorry, I missed it .. it should be, 

Dim Current_Position1 As Int64 = 0
Dim Current_Position1 As Int64 = 1

it reads as couples of bits .. index 0 & 1 , 2&3 etc .. :)

Comment: @Mona_Huththakda_Manda - good, that's what my answer assumed it should be.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you increment Count_of_Found_Pattern1 (or Pattern2), first the value is read, then it is incremented, then it assigned.  But the thread that is executing can change during those three steps.

```
Thread 1: Read Count_of_Found_Pattern1
Thread 2: Read Count_of_Found_Pattern1
Thread 2: Increment
Thread 2: Write to Count_of_Found_Pattern1
...
Thread 1: Increment its old value
Thread 1: Write to Count_of_Found_Pattern1
```

Now Count_of_Found_Pattern1 is wrong.  And if Thread 2 had control of execution for more than just one iteration, it could be very wrong.

Consider doing as much as possible within PLINQ, avoiding any mutation of global state until all the threads have joined back up. The following code assumes you're interested in comparing adjacent entries in BitArray:

```
Dim counts = Enumerable.
             Range(0, lastbitarrayover2 / 2).Select(Function(i) i * 2).
             AsParallel().
             Aggregate(
                 Function() 
                     ' We're using an object of anonymous type to hold
                     ' the results of the calculation so far.
                     ' Each thread calls this function, so each thread
                     ' gets its own object for holding intermediate results
                     Return New With {.Pattern1 = 0, .Pattern2 = 0, .Iterations = 0}
                 End Function,
                 Function(accumulator, i)
                     ' accumulator is this thread's intermediate-result-holder.
                     ' i is one of the even numbers from our big set of even numbers.
                     ' Each thread will call this function many times, building up its own accumulator object
                     ' the four conditionals from your code reduce to this If block
                     If (BitArray(i) = BitArray(i + 1)) Then
                         accumulator.Pattern2 += 1
                     Else
                         accumulator.Pattern1 += 1
                     End If
                     accumulator.Iterations += 1
                     Return accumulator
                 End Function,
                 Function(acc1, acc2)
                     ' Once each thread has built up its own accumulator object,
                     ' this function makes a new accumulator object that
                     ' combines the results from two threads.
                     ' This is called repeatedly until all the threads' results
                     ' have been combined.
                     Return New With {
                         .Pattern1 = acc1.Pattern1 + acc2.Pattern1,
                         .Pattern2 = acc1.Pattern2 + acc2.Pattern2,
                         .Iterations = acc1.Iterations + acc2.Iterations}
                 End Function,
                 Function(acc) 
                     ' The last function here is supposed to take the combined results
                     ' and turn them into what you ultimately want to use.
                     ' Since the combined results are already in the form we want,
                     ' we'll just use the "identity" function here: it returns its
                     ' argument unchanged
                     Return acc
                 End Function)

Count_of_Found_Pattern1 = counts.Pattern1
Count_of_Found_Pattern2 = counts.Pattern2
Number_of_Completed_Iterations = counts.Iterations
```

This might seem like a lot, but it's really not too bad.  The main thing is that we are giving each thread its own set of variables to work with; that way we don't have to worry about the problems I outlined at the top of my answer.  Then, we combine the work done by each thread at the end.

Comment: Is it necessary to have such amount of functions to run my code? :O .. I'm bit confused of your code. And it gives me a "syntax error" of "`New`" at `Function(acc1, acc2)
                     New With { ` .. For ordinary "for" loop, we use , `For i As Integer = 0 To 100

            sum = sum + 1
        Next`

for the same, in parallel, we use, `Parallel.For(0, 100, Sub(i) sum = sum + 1 end sub)`  ... Simple as that .. so, isn't there any main constructor for this as well ?

Comment: Can the main constructor be simple as something like this for example --> `Dim counts = Enumerable.Range (0, 100).AsParallell(). Sub (i)  DOSOMETHINGCODEHERE end sub)`  ?

Comment: And many thanks for the description of how threads work and why my code doesn't work. That was a great help indeed. :)

Comment: Thanks for the explanation :). But, still gets some errors, `.Iterations = acc1.Iterations + acc2.Iterations}
                 End Function,` (In End Function : Expression expected) , `Function(acc) acc)` ( Statement cannot appear within a method body. End of method assumed) and in `Count_of_Found_Pattern1 = counts.Pattern1` "'counts' is not declared. It may be inaccessible due to its protection level"

Comment: @Mona_Huththakda_Manda sorry, c# is my native language.  The errors should be gone now.

Comment: Further, I forgot to ask a question regarding this, how do I terminate the loop if I want to stop it ?

Comment: Just before you start a big parallel job, make a CancellationToken and make it available to whoever is interested in cancelling your computation (e.g. a UI form).  Instead of using AsParallel, use AsParallel().WithCancellation(myToken).  Then, whenever some code wants to cancel the computation, call myToken.Cancel().

Comment: thanks, and sorry, I have a lot of questions to ask about this .. another thing is while the loop runs, the main UI freezes, I can move the interface, but cant click any of the buttons or write on text boxes etc. how can I over come that problem? I thought using different threads also solves that problem as well, but apparently it isn't :(

Comment: The Aggregate function being called blocks the thread it's called on (here, the main UI thread) until all of the threads it has spawned have joined up.  I will edit my answer in a bit to reflect your requirements.

Comment: fedrspiel: did you made any changes to the code ? :) for the issue of freezing ?

Comment: I found a way, backgroundworker class, could that be a solution for the freezing ?

Comment: Yes, you can use BackgroundWorker or Task to deal with freezing (I haven't finished writing up a Task-based solution).  If the freezing was the main motivation for using parallelism and you don't mind the operation taking a little longer, you could use a normal for loop inside the BackgroundWorker or Task and skip AsParallel and Aggregate altogether, and you won't run into any problems with incorrect sums either.  I encourage making a class that can hold the results of the computation (all counts and the stopwatch) to make it easier to give the BW/Task a callback to update the UI w/ results.

Comment: No, my main concern is the speed. But I had the freezing issue as well. now it's been solved, I used your above code and wrapped it with the BackgroundWorker. Now, it works great, no more freezes :) Many Thanks Jerry Federspiel :)

And, `I encourage making a class that can hold the results of the computation (all counts and the stopwatch) to make it easier to give the BW/Task a callback to update the UI w/ results` --> I have no idea what you're talking about, can you elaborate a little bit ..

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried System.Threading.Interlocked.Increment to make this thread safe? For example:

```
If BitArray(Current_Position1) = False And BitArray(Current_Position2) = True Then
    Interlocked.Increment(Count_of_Found_Pattern1)
End If
```

Comment: when I use this, it gives me static values, the out put doesn't vary anymore, seems like this is working :)

Comment: Further, instead of `Current_Position1 = Current_Position1 + 2`, should I use  `Interlocked.Increment(Current_Position1 + 2)` ? or is there any way to do this by single line instead of writing the same code twice in two lines to get the increment by `+2` ?

Comment: or just the `interlocked.add (Current_Position1,  2)` is speedier as same as increment command.

Comment: Yes, Interlocked.Add should work well. I was focused on the mult-theading issue without too much meddling in your code. Although in the original post, it looks you are incrementing by 1.

Comment: If you don't use thread-local storage (and force the threads to compete for access to these variables) it seems like you'll lose much of the benefit of parallelization.